# Pseudocode to string - unparsed and unevaluated function input

Tags: r

How does one preserve pseudocode unparsed and unevaluated, turning it into a string?

```
f(if (?length() != 0) ?task <- ?task[-1])

# wanted output
"if (?length() != 0) ?task <- ?task[-1]"
```

`substitute`, `quote`, `deparse1`, `sys.call()[-1]`, `expression` (@IRTFM), as a formula `~{...}` give the wrong result,

```
f <- function(...) deparse1(substitute(...))

# gives
#> [1] "if (`?`(length() != 0)) `?`(task <- `?`(task[-1]))"
```

An approach that works in interactive (RStudio, RGui) environments, and terminal, but not in a `reprex::reprex()` (...?). Not ideal because history file might be large.

```
f <- function(...) {
    file <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
    savehistory(file)
    s = tail(readLines(file), 1)
    substring(s, 3, nchar(s) - 1)
}

f(if (?length() != 0) ?task <- ?task[-1])
#> [1] "if (?length() != 0) ?task <- ?task[-1]"
```

**Background**
I (naively) wanted to make R6 syntax a bit easier on the eyes while keeping its syntax highlighting.

```
# cluttered syntax, if everything is private$ or self$, none of it has to be
R6::R6Class(
    private = list(
        task = list(),
        length = \() base::length(private$task)
    ),
    public = list(
        initialize = \(...) private$task <- list(...),
        add = \(x) private$task <- c(private$task, x),
        rm = \() if (private$length() != 0) private$task <- private$task[-1]
    )
)

R6::R6Class(
    private = list(
        task = list(),
        length = \() base::length(?task)
    ),
    public = list(
        initialize = \(...) ?task <- list(...),
        add = \(x) ?task <- c(?task, x),
        rm = \() if (?length() != 0) ?task <- ?task[-1]
    )
)
```

Comment: Your string is not a valid expression in R. You can add the `expression` function to you set of R functions that refuse to be literal when handling that unquoted string. The "?" needs to be backticked and it becomes a unary operator. (The `if` function is also a reserved word.)

Comment: @IRTFM Not sure I understand the implication of *not a valid expression*, do you mean it is impossible to not have things parsed? The input here is pseudocode, the intention is to manually process / do something with it despite of `fortunes::fortune(106)`, i.e. pretty much expect it to be invalid.

Comment: "it is impossible to not have things parsed" I believe it is impossible if that "thing" is a function (R closure) argument and you want to do anything with it (e.g., turn it into a character string). Even `sys.cal` returns the parsed expression. It might be possible at the C level but I don't know enough about the parser and its place in the REPL to be sure.

Comment: @Roland Just updated the question with a workaround based on `utils::savehistory`, [C source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a984cc29b9b8d8821f8eb2a1081d9e0d1d4df56e/src/library/utils/src/stubs.c#L36-L58), that goes that route (I think) - which makes me believe some better solution is definitely possible based on it. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Your actual goal looks very similar to what data.table is doing with the `.` shortcut. They replace it with a call to `list` between parsing and evaluation. You seem to actually want to replace the shortcut with a call to `$`. Your main problem seems to result from the [low precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html) of the `?` operator. It might already be sufficient to use the unary `+` operator instead.

Comment: @Roland Good spot. Replacing `?` with `+`, then `eval(str2expression(gsub("\\+(\\w)", "private$\\1", (\(...) deparse1(substitute(...)))(<new_R6_using_+>))))` solves the immediate problem. No idea why that precedence is so low, could be a valuable unary/binary/ternary (combined with `~`) operator for use in package backends or other safe environments where help is not needed.

Comment: I don't see a need for deparsing and regex. You can (should) modify expressions (you need a recursive function for that, look at how data.table is doing it).